# setup tunnel to api gateway from local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, aws-api-gateway

I created a private API gateway route, and setup a VPC endpoint. I'm able to access the API from an EC2 using curl.

How do I setup a tunnel using aws ssm so that I can access the gateway from my local machine?

```
ssh ec2-user@i-xxx -NL 5001:xxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/abc:443 -i key.pem -v
```

Error faced in Chrome: `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

Comment: The issue is only with chrome? Can you use postman or curl to test the api on localhost:5001?

Answer (score 0):

SSH into the instance binding port 8080:

```
ssh ec2-user@i-xxx -D 8080 -i key.pem -v
```

And on my macbook, I went to settings -> network -> advanced -> proxies -> socks and added 127.0.0.1 with port 8080. Now when I am connected, traffic will be proxied to my ec2 instance.